# Leaflet Map not rendering in Rmarkdown, R Notebook when opened in browser

Tags: r, leaflet, rstudio

For some reason, I can view the leaflet map in the RStudio viewer, but not in a browser, even a very basic map.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(leaflet)
m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles()
m
```
````

All other images appear no problem when viewing the HTML file in the browser, but the map won't. Anybody run into this problem before?

Comment: Did you try different browsers/OS/machines?

Comment: I've tried with all of my browsers, Chrome, FireFox, Edge, IE, same problem. Only tried with a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `echo = F, warning = F`?

Comment: Still doesn't render, just have the regular warning 'leaflet' was built under R version 3.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong with the default tiles set. Try this:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(leaflet)
m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles(urlTemplate = 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')
m
```
````

You can find a good resource [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/basemaps.html) for alternative third-party tiles.

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Do you have any idea why the light map isn't working?

Comment: Something to do with the URL, see [this](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/386) discussion on GitHub.

Comment: Good find, thanks. For anyone else coming across this thread, I tried urlTemplate = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' for a light map and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Reposting from [GIS stack exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187926/leaflet-output-is-grey), which worked for me:

> "The solution is simply reminding leaflet what the basemap is. It
> defaults to OSM in RStudio output, but then didn't export it with
> html."

I added (repeated) the following code at the end of the all my leaflet code.

```
%>% addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just open the map in Browser instead of Viewer. The same with shiny.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).